# How can I set device rw permissions permanently on ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: udev, devices, chmod

I am using an embedded device that is running ubuntu.

Normally only root has read and write permissions for i2c devices.

I'm using this command to add i2c r/w permissions for normal user (me):

```
sudo chmod 777 /dev/i2c-*
```

But I want to create a `udev` rule. I created a file in `/etc/udev/rules.d/` called `60-i2c-tools.rules` and put the following line in it.

```
KERNEL==”i2c-[0-9]*”, MODE=”0660”
```

However, when I reboot the device, I don't have access to the I2C device. These are the permissions:

```
crwxrwxrwx 1 root root 89,  0 Aug 10 12:59 /dev/i2c-0
crwxrwxrwx 1 root root 89,  1 Aug 10 12:59 /dev/i2c-1
crw------- 1 root root 89, 10 Aug 10 12:59 /dev/i2c-10
crw------- 1 root root 89, 11 Aug 10 12:59 /dev/i2c-11
crwxrwxrwx 1 root root 89,  2 Aug 10 12:59 /dev/i2c-2
crwxrwxrwx 1 root root 89,  3 Aug 10 12:59 /dev/i2c-3
crw------- 1 root root 89,  4 Aug 10 12:59 /dev/i2c-4
crw------- 1 root root 89,  5 Aug 10 12:59 /dev/i2c-5
crw------- 1 root root 89,  6 Aug 10 12:59 /dev/i2c-6
crw------- 1 root root 89,  7 Aug 10 12:59 /dev/i2c-7
crw------- 1 root root 89,  8 Aug 10 12:59 /dev/i2c-8
crw------- 1 root root 89,  9 Aug 10 12:59 /dev/i2c-9
```

I need to run `sudo chmod 777 /dev/i2c-*` and the permissions change to:

```
crwxrwxrwx 1 root root 89,  0 Aug 10 12:59 /dev/i2c-0
crwxrwxrwx 1 root root 89,  1 Aug 10 12:59 /dev/i2c-1
crwxrwxrwx 1 root root 89, 10 Aug 10 12:59 /dev/i2c-10
crwxrwxrwx 1 root root 89, 11 Aug 10 12:59 /dev/i2c-11
crwxrwxrwx 1 root root 89,  2 Aug 10 12:59 /dev/i2c-2
crwxrwxrwx 1 root root 89,  3 Aug 10 12:59 /dev/i2c-3
crwxrwxrwx 1 root root 89,  4 Aug 10 12:59 /dev/i2c-4
crwxrwxrwx 1 root root 89,  5 Aug 10 12:59 /dev/i2c-5
crwxrwxrwx 1 root root 89,  6 Aug 10 12:59 /dev/i2c-6
crwxrwxrwx 1 root root 89,  7 Aug 10 12:59 /dev/i2c-7
crwxrwxrwx 1 root root 89,  8 Aug 10 12:59 /dev/i2c-8
crwxrwxrwx 1 root root 89,  9 Aug 10 12:59 /dev/i2c-9
```

Comment: Does your rule *really* use non-ASCII quotes? if so, that would be the first thing to fix. Beyond that, it's probably better practice to create a user-group for the device and assign *that* using a udev rule (in a similar way to the `dialout` group for serial devices)

Comment: 1) If the device is created on boot, the `udev` rules must be in the initramfs part of the image. Changing them on the harddisk is not enough. 2) Verify with `udevadm`, `modprobe` etc. that the rule works as intended.

Comment: Why do you want to change permissions of device files? This is crazy, please do not change the permission's of device files. This can cause major damage. Edited to make this point. This was my main point.